# How do I notify a c++ future without setting a value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a thread waiting on a future. In the event where my application is shut down, I would like to join the thread. How do I go about notifying the future without fudging it and setting it to some value?

```
auto promise = std::promise<std::string>();
...
auto future = promise.get_future();
auto consumer = std::thread([&]
{
   while (future.wait_for(10ms)){
       // do something
       std::cout << future.get().c_str();
   }
});
...
consumer.join();
```

Comment: If the `std::promise` is destroyed, the future will be notified and `get` will throw a [`std::future_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future_error). That's how you would "abandon" a promise/future. You can also try setting an exception for the `std::promise`. In both cases the thread will need to catch an exception.

Comment: If the application is shutting down, and you just don't want to throw an exception for terminating an active thread, you can `detach()` it instead of joining it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Having threads persisting after the end of main leads to all sorts of portability headaches.  I'd strongly advise against it.

Comment: Given that this is not an 'exceptional' circumstance, I would prefer to not set an exception on the promise. To @Yakk-AdamNevraumont's point, I do not want to detach the thread.

Comment: You look like you might want your thread to wait until signalled, then do something, then wait again until signalled, then do something, etc, and only exit when told explicitly to do so.  Is this in fact the case?  The code as posted is a bit confusing.

Comment: @PaulSanders essentially I am exploring whether I can replace that idiom with a promise/future approach.

Comment: Just like real life, the thing with a promise is that you can only use it once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So std threading primitives are primitives.  They are ok for direct use in toy applications, where "shut down early" means "tell the OS to shut down the process".

For more complex applications, you need to build things up from them.

You'll want thread pools instead of using raw threads, you'll probably want continuations of thread tasks, and you'll want a shutdown architecture.

One way to implement a shutdown architecture is to use exceptions.  If all of your outstanding future's have promises in a central bit of code, you can [set exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_exception) on them.  Or destroy the promises.  Both result in people waiting on the futures to get an exception thrown.

Or you can enforce that *all* of your promises/futures are actually `future<optional<T>>` and use "nullopt" to say "we are shutting down".  Or use `future<expected<T,Error>>`.

On the other hand, if your async code is based on continuations (including "continue into a task queue for idle processing on main thread" and "continue into another async task"), you can have a policy for when the source of a continuation has failed.  Some continuation systems give the next one something like an `std::experimental::expected<Data, Error>`.  Others hand it a ready-or-error-state `std::future<Data>`.  In other cases, abandoned inputs of continutations cause the continuation to become abandoned automatically.

Shutting down a C++ application is hard, especially if you want to do it on-demand.  It basically requires a global event that rolls-down all control paths in the app in a clean way.  There isn't an easy answer.  There are many easy ways you can get it to sort of work in a way that doesn't seem to cause any immediate problems, like "just detach the thread" or "just call `exit`".